# Stellar-core running in Docker container, but not inside supervisorctl. If run in supervisorctl it doesn't use the right config

Tags: stellar-core, docker, stellar.toml

In the docker container if I run stellar-core using supervisortctl, then logs do not get written to the file I have specified in my stellar-core.cfg, but if I start stellar-core outside of supervisorctl (run the stellar-core command inside the docker container) it does.

However I would like to have all 3 of my processes (core, horizon, postgres) all running inside of supervisor if possible. Any ideas why this is the case?

e.g. my stellar core is currently running fine (And writing logs to the correct file), but supervisorctl command displays:

```
supervisorctl
horizon                          RUNNING   pid 21, uptime X days
postgresql                       RUNNING   pid 19, uptime X days
stellar-core                     STOPPED   X date
```

Does anyone know the steps I should take to try and get my stellar-core running inside supervisorctl as well (and have it continue logging to the correct file)?

When I try starting stellar-core inside supervisorctl while it is already running the following:

```
supervisor> start stellar-core
stellar-core: ERROR (spawn error)
```

or

```
stellar-core                     FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
supervisor> restart stellar-core
stellar-core: ERROR (not running)
stellar-core: ERROR (spawn error)
```

But of course there is no log for this process as far as I can tell.

Comment: 1. you dont run processes "inside" supervisor. its not a docker-like mechanism: you simply let supervisor run them for you and it restarts them if they fail.
2. please provide the supervisor configurations (/etc/supervisor) for your processes.
3. by default, supervisor sends logs to /var/log/supervisor/ anything in there?

Comment: There are. Supervisor logs read https://pastebin.com/raw/VhYka9gF